# the next square number is $(? )^2 = a_{1}a_{2}\cdots $ where $a_{i}$ is consecutive positive integer

Tags: number-theory

Today:
I found this interesting fact

$$18^2=324,\quad 24^2=576,\quad 66^2=4356$$

**my Question:**

then next   square numbers is ?

such as $$(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots)^2=a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots$$  where $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\cdots$ is consecutive positive integer,

such

$18^2=324$,then $2,3,4$ is consecutive positive integer.

$24^2=576$,then $5,6,7$ is consecutive positive integer.

$66^2=4356$,then $3,4,5,6$ is consecutive positive integer

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking for square numbers, all of whose digits are consecutive (but these can be in any order)? Do you allow one-digit squares? Presumably you do not allow repetitions, so there are no such squares $\ge 10^{10}$ (so you can stop looking for $a$ at $10^{5}$).

Comment: Yes,I have edit, my problem   not allow repetitions,Now can you understand my problem?

Answer (score 2):

By brute force, the next few are

```
74 5476
152 23104
179 32041
3678 13527684
3698 13675204
4175 17430625
4616 21307456
5904 34857216
5968 35617024
6596 43507216
7532 56731024
8082 65318724
8559 73256481
9024 81432576
```

There are another 52 with 9-digit squares, and 87 with 10-digit squares; the largest is $99066^2 = 9814072356$.